# Show that a transposition cannot be written as a product of 3-cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

> Show that, working in $Sn$ with $n \geq 4$, a transposition cannot be written as a product of 3-cycles.

With $n=4$, for instance, we cannot write them as a product of 3-cycles, but we can write them as a product of 2-cycles. Thus, transpositions cannot be written as a product of 3-cycles.

I am not sure how to prove this. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A 3 cycle can be broken down to 2 transpositions.  Any combination of an even number of transpositions is an even number of transpositions.

Comment: Transpositions are odd permutations, and $3$-cycles are even.